# Angular2 Reactive Forms - Disable form control dynamically from condition

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a select control that I want to disable dynamically based on a condition:

```
this.activityForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  docType: [{ value: '2', disabled: this.activeCategory != 'document' }, Validators.required]
});
```

However, docType doesn't become enabled even though at some point this.activeCategory becomes 'document'.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since I don't know how you're manipulating `activeCategory` (maybe it's also a `FormControl`?), I'll suggest the following approach:

You can use `(change)` to detect when `this.activeCategory` has changed, as below:

1 - If you're using `ngModel`:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="activeCategory" (change)="checkValue($event)">
```

2 - If it's a `FormControl`:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="activeCategory" (change)="checkValue($event)">
```

So, in component, you can manipulate the `docType` *control* using `disable/enable` methods:

```
checkValue(event: Event) {
  const ctrl = this.activityForm.get('docType');

  if (event.value === 'document') {
    ctrl.enable();
  } else {
    ctrl.disable();
  }
}
```

Comment: On option 2: if it's a FormControl I recommend subscribing to  
```
this.form.get('activeCategory').valueChanges
```

instead of putting logic on DOM.

Answer (score 10):

You have to handle select elements differently than you do other HTML elements. You will have to perform a reset when `this.activeCategory` changes.

Something like this:

`this.activityForm.controls['docType'].reset({ value: '2', disabled: false });`

Of course, you will probably want to use the current value, rather than a hard coded `'2'`.

Same sort of thing to disable it, if that need arises (and it probably will).

`this.activityForm.controls['docType'].reset({ value: '2', disabled: true });`

More information on ng form control [reset](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html#!#reset-anchor).

Comment: Is there a nicer way of doing this? With say `setValue` or `patchValue`?

Comment: @Kody For enabling/disabling a select, not that I am aware of. `setValue` and `patchValue` are for changing the form controls value, not visual state.

Answer (score 1):

from .ts file you can add keys to yours from controls,
 and there you add the item disabled:true (desactivate form item) 
or false (activate form item)

.ts

```
public form_name=new FormGroup({

              series: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}),
              inten: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}),
              rep: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}),
              rest: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: false}),
              observation: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: false}),



  });
```

.html

```
<form  [formGroup]="form_name" >

                                          <label for="series"  >Series</label>
                                           <input type="text" formControlName="series" >

                                          <label for="inten"  >Inten</label>
                                           <input type="text" formControlName="inten" >

                                          <label for="rep"  >Rep</label>
                                           <input type="text" formControlName="rep" >

                                           <label for="rest"  >rest</label>
                                            <textarea formControlName="rest" rows="3" cols="30" ></textarea>


                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.activityForm.controls['docType'].disable();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -2):

you can use ternary operator here to disable form control conditionally.

```
this.activityForm = this.formBuilder.group({
docType: [{ value: '2', disabled: this.activeCategory != 'document' ? true : false }, Validators.required]
});
```