# Angular checkbox cannot be disabled

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui

```
<input type="checkbox" kendoCheckBox id="syncToCDS-checkbox" class="k-checkbox" name="SyncToCDS" formControlName="SyncToCDS" [readonly]="true"> // never disabled
<input type="checkbox" kendoCheckBox id="syncToCDS-checkbox" class="k-checkbox" name="SyncToCDS" formControlName="SyncToCDS" [disabled]="true"> // never disabled
<input type="checkbox" kendoCheckBox id="syncToCDS-checkbox" class="k-checkbox" name="SyncToCDS" formControlName="SyncToCDS" [attr.disabled]="false"> //always disabled
```

When I inspect the [disabled] element, I see `ng-reflect-is-disabled="true"` on the input. I can't seem to get the input working properly, and would like to avoid this (which does actually work):

```
<input type="checkbox" *ngIf="cannotUnsyncCDS" disabled kendoCheckBox id="syncToCDS-checkbox" class="k-checkbox" formControlName="SyncToCDS">
<input type="checkbox" *ngIf="!cannotUnsyncCDS" kendoCheckBox id="syncToCDS-checkbox" class="k-checkbox" formControlName="SyncToCDS">
```

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990430/angular2-reactive-forms-disable-form-control-dynamically-from-condition/43990705#43990705), or any other answer on the post helps you.

Comment: I'd prefer to handle it from the HTML instead of adding code to the js. It looks like a valid workaround though

Answer (score 1):

you can use angular form controls disable method to disable a form control or disable all controls of form group.

To disable a form control:

```
this.yourFormGroupName.controls.SyncToCDS.disable();
```

To disable all controls:

```
this.yourFormGroupNanme.disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Kendo-UI depends on jquery version.
I faced same problem before, so please check your jquery version with Kendo-UI

Comment: I'm using angular so no jquery is included in the app